# List of WebElements by Selenium and Java

Tags: java, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, findelement

I am get the elements of a tag from below part of HTML.

```
<div id="Ad-2details">
    <div class="H3">
        <a id=...></a>
        <a id=...></a>
        <a id=...></a>"
```

And my part of source code is;

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("AD-2details"));
List<WebElement> elementList = element.findElements(By.className("H3"));
```

This code work correctly on old version of Selenium, but current version(4.1.2) make exception as;

```
Command: [3e995689fe46b9177a7a7821e9a6e59d, findChildElements {id=0.37748117883484866-1, using=class, value=H3}]
```

Question:
Current version of Selenium does not get data from above type HTML?
If no, how can I get data from above type HTML?

Comment: this issue is not related to version of selenium, `element.findElements(By.tagName("a"));` should work

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML:

```
<div id="Ad-2details">
    <div class="H3">
        <a id=...></a>
        <a id=...></a>
        <a id=...></a>
```

this line of code:

```
findElements(By.className("H3");
```

would always identify the **only** *`<div>`* node with **`class="H3"`**

Hence, you find only a single list entry as:

```
[3e995689fe46b9177a7a7821e9a6e59d, findChildElements {id=0.37748117883484866-1, using=class, value=H3}]
```

---

### Solution

To get all the `<a>` tag elements you need to reach till the *`<a>`* tag and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("AD-2details"));
  List<WebElement> elementList = element.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.H3 a"));
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("AD-2details"));
  List<WebElement> elementList = element.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='H3']//a"));
  ```

In a single line:

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  List<WebElement> elementList = element.findElements(By.cssSelector("div#Ad-2details div.H3 a"));
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  List<WebElement> elementList = element.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='Ad-2details']/div[@class='H3']//a"));
  ```

Comment: I could get WebElement list by your sggestion.
BY the way, does behavior for findElement or findElemets argument of By.className changed between old version?